# error in deploy weblogic 12c server

Tags: java, windows, native, netbeans-7, weblogic12c

Thanks for the initial response which solved the weblogic problem presented
 Now i am faced with a new problem which wont allow my weblogic to start in netbeans 7. See below part of the verbose log:

```
To allow the Platform MBeanServer to be used, either remove the system properties and JVM options or start WebLogic Server with the following system property:
 -Djavax.management.builder.initial=weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerBuilder 
 To eliminate this log error if Platform MBeans do not need to be available when using WebLogic Server, set the PlatformMBeanUsed attribute in the JMXMBean to false.> 
.
 A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007711000a, pid=3912, tid=6732
#
# JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000007711000a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of  Windows
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\base_domain\hs_err_pid3912.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.


RESULTS OF hs_err_pid3912.log:
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x000000007711000a, pid=3912, tid=6732
#
# JRE version: 7.0_02-b13
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (22.0-b10 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x000000007711000a
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000099ef000):  JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[3]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6732, stack(0x0000000010820000,0x0000000010920000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x0000000077112008

Registers:
RAX=0x000000000000000f, RBX=0x0000000000000000, RCX=0x000000001091d3a0, RDX=0x00000000001f0003
RSP=0x000000001091d368, RBP=0x0000000000000000, RSI=0x0000000000000000, RDI=0x0000000000000000
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000000000001, R10=0x0000000077111f94, R11=0x000000001091d4f8
R12=0x0000000000000001, R13=0x0000000000000068, R14=0x000000001091d520, R15=0x000000000012000f
RIP=0x000000007711000a, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010212

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000001091d368)
0x000000001091d368:   000007fefd0d38d2 0000000000000000
0x000000001091d378:   0000000000000000 000000001091d4e0
0x000000001091d388:   000000000000004a 0000000000000000
0x000000001091d398:   000007fefd0d673b 0000000000000049
0x000000001091d3a8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001091d3b8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000092
0x000000001091d3c8:   000000001091d4d0 0000000000000001
0x000000001091d3d8:   000007fefc3f12ea 0000000000000049
0x000000001091d3e8:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x000000001091d3f8:   0000000000000000 000000001091d520
0x000000001091d408:   0000000000000068 000000001091d508
0x000000001091d418:   000007fefdbe1076 0000000000000000
0x000000001091d428:   0000000000000001 0000000000000049
0x000000001091d438:   0000000000000000 00000000060e4710
0x000000001091d448:   00000000060e4720 000000001091d4e0
0x000000001091d458:   000000000000004a 0000000000000000 

Instructions: (pc=0x000000007711000a)
0x000000007710ffea:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x000000000000000f is an unknown value
RBX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RCX=0x000000001091d3a0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000099ef000
RDX=0x00000000001f0003 is an unknown value
RSP=0x000000001091d368 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000099ef000
RBP=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RDI=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R10=0x0000000077111f94 is an unknown value
R11=0x000000001091d4f8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000099ef000
R12=0x0000000000000001 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000068 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000001091d520 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000099ef000
R15=0x000000000012000f is an unknown value


Stack: [0x0000000010820000,0x0000000010920000],  sp=0x000000001091d368,  free space=1012k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x000000007711000a

[error occurred during error reporting (printing native stack), id 0xc0000005]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.getHostByAddr([B)Ljava/lang/String;+0
j  java.net.InetAddress$1.getHostByAddr([B)Ljava/lang/String;+4
j  java.net.InetAddress.getHostFromNameService(Ljava/net/InetAddress;Z)Ljava/lang/String;+37
j  java.net.InetAddress.getHostName(Z)Ljava/lang/String;+10
j  java.net.InetAddress.getHostName()Ljava/lang/String;+2
j  weblogic.server.channels.DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.open()V+125
j  weblogic.server.channels.DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter.access$100(Lweblogic/server/channels/DynamicListenThread$SocketAccepter;)V+1
j  weblogic.server.channels.DynamicListenThread.run()V+13
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000935b000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[4]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5476, stack(0x0000000013660000,0x0000000013760000)]
  0x000000000935a800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[2]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6984, stack(0x0000000013760000,0x0000000013860000)]
  0x0000000009359800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[7]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6844, stack(0x00000000134c0000,0x00000000135c0000)]
  0x0000000009359000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[9]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6200, stack(0x00000000131a0000,0x00000000132a0000)]
  0x0000000009358000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[9]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4348, stack(0x0000000013320000,0x0000000013420000)]
  0x0000000009357800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[2]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3808, stack(0x0000000013080000,0x0000000013180000)]
  0x0000000009357000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[5]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2212, stack(0x0000000012c00000,0x0000000012d00000)]
  0x0000000009356000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[11]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5992, stack(0x0000000012f70000,0x0000000013070000)]
  0x0000000007c15800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[6]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4968, stack(0x0000000012d80000,0x0000000012e80000)]
  0x0000000007c14800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6412, stack(0x0000000012af0000,0x0000000012bf0000)]
  0x0000000007c14000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[8]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4112, stack(0x0000000012960000,0x0000000012a60000)]
  0x0000000007c13000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[11]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3908, stack(0x0000000011b30000,0x0000000011c30000)]
  0x0000000007c12800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[9]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4932, stack(0x0000000012850000,0x0000000012950000)]
  0x0000000007c12000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[3]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3328, stack(0x0000000011f40000,0x0000000012040000)]
  0x0000000007c11000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[8]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6408, stack(0x0000000011d30000,0x0000000011e30000)]
  0x0000000007c10800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[5]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4840, stack(0x0000000012660000,0x0000000012760000)]
  0x0000000007c0f800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[8]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6192, stack(0x00000000124f0000,0x00000000125f0000)]
  0x0000000007c0f000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[1]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7120, stack(0x0000000012380000,0x0000000012480000)]
  0x0000000007c0e000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[10]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6348, stack(0x0000000012210000,0x0000000012310000)]
  0x00000000099f5000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[4]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4060, stack(0x00000000120a0000,0x00000000121a0000)]
  0x00000000099f4000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[5]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3028, stack(0x0000000011e30000,0x0000000011f30000)]
  0x00000000099f3800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[3]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6496, stack(0x0000000011c30000,0x0000000011d30000)]
  0x00000000099f2800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[4]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6852, stack(0x00000000118b0000,0x00000000119b0000)]
  0x00000000099f2000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[11]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6432, stack(0x0000000011a30000,0x0000000011b30000)]
  0x00000000099f1000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5172, stack(0x00000000117b0000,0x00000000118b0000)]
  0x00000000099f0800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[3]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4740, stack(0x0000000011630000,0x0000000011730000)]
  0x00000000099ef800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[11]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6464, stack(0x00000000114b0000,0x00000000115b0000)]
=>0x00000000099ef000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[3]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6732, stack(0x0000000010820000,0x0000000010920000)]
  0x00000000099ee800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[6]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5936, stack(0x00000000112c0000,0x00000000113c0000)]
  0x00000000099ed800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[1]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5768, stack(0x00000000111b0000,0x00000000112b0000)]
  0x00000000099ed000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[2]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4744, stack(0x00000000110a0000,0x00000000111a0000)]
  0x00000000099ec000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[1]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5488, stack(0x0000000010ec0000,0x0000000010fc0000)]
  0x00000000099eb800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[6]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2996, stack(0x0000000010ce0000,0x0000000010de0000)]
  0x00000000099ea800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[4]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1752, stack(0x0000000010bd0000,0x0000000010cd0000)]
  0x00000000099ea000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[7]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6100, stack(0x0000000010ac0000,0x0000000010bc0000)]
  0x00000000099e9000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[10]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2888, stack(0x0000000010950000,0x0000000010a50000)]
  0x00000000099e8800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[6]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7148, stack(0x00000000106b0000,0x00000000107b0000)]
  0x00000000099e7800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[2]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6700, stack(0x00000000104b0000,0x00000000105b0000)]
  0x00000000099e7000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[7]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4860, stack(0x00000000102b0000,0x00000000103b0000)]
  0x00000000099e6800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure[10]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=868, stack(0x000000000fed0000,0x000000000ffd0000)]
  0x00000000099e5800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[1]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6188, stack(0x0000000010150000,0x0000000010250000)]
  0x0000000007cba000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6988, stack(0x0000000010030000,0x0000000010130000)]
  0x0000000007cb9000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[5]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=2636, stack(0x000000000fd70000,0x000000000fe70000)]
  0x0000000007cb8800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[9]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4888, stack(0x000000000fb90000,0x000000000fc90000)]
  0x0000000007cb7800 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[sip[8]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7060, stack(0x000000000f7c0000,0x000000000f8c0000)]
  0x0000000007cb7000 JavaThread "DynamicListenThread[Default[10]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=924, stack(0x000000000fa30000,0x000000000fb30000)]
  0x0000000007cb6000 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[DefaultSecure]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=3236, stack(0x000000000f8e0000,0x000000000f9e0000)]
  0x0000000007cb5800 JavaThread "DynamicJSSEListenThread[sips[7]]" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=5708, stack(0x000000000e600000,0x000000000e700000)]
  0x0000000007cb4800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '16' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4632, stack(0x000000000f670000,0x000000000f770000)]
  0x0000000007cb4000 JavaThread "weblogic.GCMonitor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4892, stack(0x000000000f510000,0x000000000f610000)]
  0x0000000007cb3800 JavaThread "Thread-19" [_thread_blocked, id=6840, stack(0x000000000f300000,0x000000000f400000)]
  0x0000000007cb2800 JavaThread "Timer-5" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6280, stack(0x000000000f1b0000,0x000000000f2b0000)]
  0x0000000007558800 JavaThread "Timer-4" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2500, stack(0x000000000f010000,0x000000000f110000)]
  0x0000000007558000 JavaThread "Timer-3" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6788, stack(0x000000000ee20000,0x000000000ef20000)]
  0x0000000007557000 JavaThread "pool-3-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=3652, stack(0x000000000ed10000,0x000000000ee10000)]
  0x0000000007556800 JavaThread "Timer-2" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3432, stack(0x000000000eb70000,0x000000000ec70000)]
  0x0000000007555800 JavaThread "LazyClock" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4224, stack(0x000000000ea30000,0x000000000eb30000)]
  0x0000000007555000 JavaThread "Thread-13" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=4908, stack(0x000000000e890000,0x000000000e990000)]
  0x0000000007554800 JavaThread "Thread-12" [_thread_blocked, id=6036, stack(0x000000000e790000,0x000000000e890000)]
  0x0000000007553800 JavaThread "Thread-11" [_thread_blocked, id=5496, stack(0x000000000e3e0000,0x000000000e4e0000)]
  0x0000000007553000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '15' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6096, stack(0x000000000d070000,0x000000000d170000)]
  0x0000000007551800 JavaThread "Thread-10" [_thread_blocked, id=3556, stack(0x000000000cf20000,0x000000000d020000)]
  0x0000000007552000 JavaThread "DoSManager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6048, stack(0x000000000c500000,0x000000000c600000)]
  0x0000000007550800 JavaThread "VDE Transaction Processor Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4296, stack(0x000000000b600000,0x000000000b700000)]
  0x0000000007550000 JavaThread "ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6164, stack(0x000000000c0a0000,0x000000000c1a0000)]
  0x000000000754f000 JavaThread "ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.socket.Muxer'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=1004, stack(0x000000000beb0000,0x000000000bfb0000)]
  0x000000000754e800 JavaThread "weblogic.timers.TimerThread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3596, stack(0x000000000b780000,0x000000000b880000)]
  0x000000000754e000 JavaThread "weblogic.time.TimeEventGenerator" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2584, stack(0x000000000b260000,0x000000000b360000)]
  0x000000000754d000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '14' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=7140, stack(0x000000000b500000,0x000000000b600000)]
  0x000000000754c800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '13' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=4876, stack(0x000000000b040000,0x000000000b140000)]
  0x000000000754b800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '12' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2460, stack(0x000000000b370000,0x000000000b470000)]
  0x000000000754b000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '11' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1268, stack(0x000000000b140000,0x000000000b240000)]
  0x000000000754a000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '10' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3424, stack(0x000000000af00000,0x000000000b000000)]
  0x0000000007549800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '9' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6416, stack(0x000000000acc0000,0x000000000adc0000)]
  0x0000000007718000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '8' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5144, stack(0x000000000a320000,0x000000000a420000)]
  0x00000000074c9000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '7' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5448, stack(0x000000000a530000,0x000000000a630000)]
  0x0000000007530000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '6' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2876, stack(0x000000000ab00000,0x000000000ac00000)]
  0x00000000075c0000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '5' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2432, stack(0x000000000a9d0000,0x000000000aad0000)]
  0x00000000075e8000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '4' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=6148, stack(0x000000000a8a0000,0x000000000a9a0000)]
  0x0000000007860800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '3' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_in_vm, id=6068, stack(0x000000000a780000,0x000000000a880000)]
  0x000000000772d000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '2' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6240, stack(0x000000000a650000,0x000000000a750000)]
  0x0000000006cf7800 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '1' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2264, stack(0x000000000a430000,0x000000000a530000)]
  0x00000000091f4000 JavaThread "[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2592, stack(0x000000000a1a0000,0x000000000a2a0000)]
  0x00000000083f6000 JavaThread "Timer-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3748, stack(0x0000000009fe0000,0x000000000a0e0000)]
  0x00000000075c5800 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2924, stack(0x0000000009e50000,0x0000000009f50000)]
  0x000000000590f800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2568, stack(0x00000000066b0000,0x00000000067b0000)]
  0x0000000005905000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1816, stack(0x0000000006430000,0x0000000006530000)]
  0x00000000058ec000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3516, stack(0x0000000006550000,0x0000000006650000)]
  0x00000000058e7000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6364, stack(0x0000000005fb0000,0x00000000060b0000)]
  0x00000000058e5800 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3756, stack(0x0000000006280000,0x0000000006380000)]
  0x000000000585f000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5300, stack(0x0000000006170000,0x0000000006270000)]
  0x0000000005856000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6120, stack(0x0000000005db0000,0x0000000005eb0000)]
  0x0000000001ec2000 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=784, stack(0x0000000002240000,0x0000000002340000)]

Other Threads:
  0x0000000005851000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000005eb0000,0x0000000005fb0000] [id=7136]
  0x0000000005918800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000068f0000,0x00000000069f0000] [id=5516]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 121664K, used 87655K [0x00000000f5560000, 0x00000000ffa80000, 0x0000000100000000)
  eden space 81792K, 76% used [0x00000000f5560000,0x00000000f922e380,0x00000000fa540000)
  from space 39872K, 63% used [0x00000000fd390000,0x00000000fec5bc40,0x00000000ffa80000)
  to   space 43648K, 0% used [0x00000000fa540000,0x00000000fa540000,0x00000000fcfe0000)
 PSOldGen        total 174784K, used 59563K [0x00000000e0000000, 0x00000000eaab0000, 0x00000000f5560000)
  object space 174784K, 34% used [0x00000000e0000000,0x00000000e3a2af30,0x00000000eaab0000)
 PSPermGen       total 131072K, used 88532K [0x00000000d0000000, 0x00000000d8000000, 0x00000000e0000000)
  object space 131072K, 67% used [0x00000000d0000000,0x00000000d5675178,0x00000000d8000000)

Code Cache  [0x0000000002340000, 0x00000000025b0000, 0x0000000005340000)
 total_blobs=1193 nmethods=630 adapters=515 free_code_cache=47244Kb largest_free_block=48310144

Dynamic libraries:
0x000000013f360000 - 0x000000013f393000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\bin\java.exe
0x0000000076f60000 - 0x0000000077109000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x0000000076d40000 - 0x0000000076e5f000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x000007fefd0d0000 - 0x000007fefd13b000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x0000000070da0000 - 0x0000000070dea000     C:\Program Files\AVAST Software\Avast\snxhk64.dll
0x000007feff020000 - 0x000007feff0fb000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x000007fefee20000 - 0x000007fefeebf000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x000007fefe060000 - 0x000007fefe07f000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x000007fefde60000 - 0x000007fefdf8d000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x0000000076e60000 - 0x0000000076f5a000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x000007fefd8f0000 - 0x000007fefd957000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x000007fefee10000 - 0x000007fefee1e000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x000007feff1a0000 - 0x000007feff269000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x000007fefb7c0000 - 0x000007fefb9b4000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.7601.17514_none_fa396087175ac9ac\COMCTL32.dll
0x000007feff100000 - 0x000007feff171000     C:\Windows\system32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x000007fefdf90000 - 0x000007fefdfbe000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x000007fefd170000 - 0x000007fefd279000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x000000006a420000 - 0x000000006a4f1000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000068790000 - 0x0000000068e6a000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x000007feef400000 - 0x000007feef409000     C:\Windows\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x000007fefdb90000 - 0x000007fefdbdd000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x000007fefdbe0000 - 0x000007fefdbe8000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x000007fefae80000 - 0x000007fefaebb000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x0000000077130000 - 0x0000000077137000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00000000743a0000 - 0x00000000743af000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000074370000 - 0x0000000074398000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000074350000 - 0x0000000074365000     C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x000000006de20000 - 0x000000006de39000     C:\RESoft Solutions\jdk7\jre\bin\net.dll
0x000007fefc570000 - 0x000007fefc5c5000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x000007fefc560000 - 0x000007fefc567000     C:\Windows\System32\wship6.dll
0x000007fefaec0000 - 0x000007fefaed5000     C:\Windows\system32\NLAapi.dll
0x000007fef8cd0000 - 0x000007fef8ce5000     C:\Windows\system32\napinsp.dll
0x000007fef8cb0000 - 0x000007fef8cc9000     C:\Windows\system32\pnrpnsp.dll
0x000007fefc3f0000 - 0x000007fefc44b000     C:\Windows\system32\DNSAPI.dll
0x000007fef8ca0000 - 0x000007fef8cab000     C:\Windows\System32\winrnr.dll
0x000007fef8c70000 - 0x000007fef8c9e000     C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live\WLIDNSP.DLL
0x000007fef8c60000 - 0x000007fef8c70000     C:\Windows\system32\wshbth.dll
0x0000000070bc0000 - 0x0000000070be6000     C:\Program Files\Bonjour\mdnsNSP.dll
0x000007fefab90000 - 0x000007fefabb7000     C:\Windows\system32\Iphlpapi.DLL
0x000007fefab60000 - 0x000007fefab6b000     C:\Windows\system32\WINNSI.DLL
0x000007fefbf20000 - 0x000007fefbf27000     C:\Windows\System32\wshtcpip.dll
0x000007fef8080000 - 0x000007fef8088000     C:\Windows\system32\rasadhlp.dll
0x000007fefa560000 - 0x000007fefa5b3000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x000000006e020000 - 0x000000006e031000     C:\RESoft Solutions\jdk7\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x0000000074340000 - 0x000000007434b000     C:\RESoft Solutions\jdk7\jre\bin\management.dll
0x000007fefc5d0000 - 0x000007fefc5e7000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTSP.dll
0x000007fefc2d0000 - 0x000007fefc317000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
0x000007fefc040000 - 0x000007fefc05e000     C:\Windows\system32\USERENV.dll
0x000007fefcd40000 - 0x000007fefcd4f000     C:\Windows\system32\profapi.dll
0x000007fefcc30000 - 0x000007fefcc3f000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x000007fefa980000 - 0x000007fefa998000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc.DLL
0x000007fefa960000 - 0x000007fefa971000     C:\Windows\system32\dhcpcsvc6.DLL
0x0000000010000000 - 0x0000000010008000     C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\native\win\x64\wlntio.dll
0x000000006a3f0000 - 0x000000006a414000     C:\RESoft Solutions\jdk7\jre\bin\sunec.dll
0x00000000742a0000 - 0x00000000742ab000     C:\RESoft Solutions\jdk7\jre\bin\sunmscapi.dll
0x000007fefcdf0000 - 0x000007fefcf5c000     C:\Windows\system32\CRYPT32.dll
0x000007fefcde0000 - 0x000007fefcdef000     C:\Windows\system32\MSASN1.dll
0x00000000005e0000 - 0x00000000005f8000     C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\server\native\win\x64\wlfileio3.dll
0x000007fef8cf0000 - 0x000007fef8e15000     C:\Windows\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.policy -Xverify:none -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\RES~1\jdk7/jre/lib/endorsed;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1/endorsed -ea:com.bea.wcp... -da -Dplatform.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1 -Dwls.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server -Dweblogic.home=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server -Dweblogic.management.discover=true -Dwlw.iterativeDev= -Dwlw.testConsole= -Dwlw.logErrorsToConsole= -Dweblogic.ext.dirs=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sysext_manifest_classpath 
java_command: weblogic.Server
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\RES~1\jdk7
CLASSPATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\sys_manifest_classpath\weblogic_patch.jar;C:\RES~1\jdk7\lib\tools.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic_sp.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\weblogic.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\features\weblogic.server.modules_12.1.1.0.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\webservices.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1/lib/ant-all.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\NETSFA~1.0_1/lib/ant-contrib.jar;C:\Oracle\Middleware\wlserver_12.1\sip\server\lib\weblogic_sip.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\common\derby\lib\derbyclient.jar;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\lib\xqrl.jar;.;C:\Progra~2\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip
PATH=C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_wls1211\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\patch_ocp371\profiles\default\native;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\x64;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\modules\ORGAPA~1.1\bin;C:\RES~1\jdk7\jre\bin;C:\RES~1\jdk7\bin;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\bin;;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\cygwin\bin;C:\Oracle\MIDDLE~1\WLSERV~1.1\server\native\win\x64\oci920_8
```

the above is a verbose from an error log showing the caus eof the problems

Comment: Did you actually try setting the JVM option as described in the message?

Comment: i think the problem was with jvm incompatibility. i had to reinstall the whole thing again but this time pointing to jdk 1.6 as opposed to 1.7 and it started.